# Facebook permissions giving undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a simple information from a person's(me) profile by asking permission in the scope section while prompting the user to login in. However, I am getting undefined as my result. I am using facebook's quick  start for [javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#login) sdk. Even when I ask for first_name, which is in the response after logging in, I get undefined. Here is a small snippet of the quick start code. All I am doing is changing response.name to response.first_name. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,first_name'}, function(response) {
  ...
});
```

It is called "Declarative Fields", you have to specify which fields you want to get or you will only get the id and the name.

Make sure the user is authorized, of course. Here´s a tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: it worked. Thanks @luschin. But what should I write to get user_hometown?

Comment: well...how about this: {fields: 'name,first_name,user_hometown'}

Comment: @luschin, I tried that already. It doesn't work. I added user_hometown in my scope and also in the fields. I can only get first name, last name. But for more privileges like gender, hometown or birthday, it doesn't work :(

Comment: then you did not authorize correctly. make sure you really get asked for the user_hometown permission in the auth process. - or you did not set a hometown, which is also possible.